# Integration of $\sin(x)^{\sin(x)}$

Tags: integration

What is the general solution for the following integration question? More importantly, how is one to proceed in such situations?

$$
\int \sin(x)^{\sin(x)}\mathrm dx
$$

Comment: This may not have an indefinite integral.

Comment: In what context does this integral occur ?

Comment: In particular when $\sin x \lt 0$, taking fractional powers $\sin x$ becomes fraught with ill-defined values.

Answer (score 1):

The integral will only be defined over domains where $\sin x \gt 0$ (or at points where $\sin x = -1$ but those are isolated).  There is no reason to expect to be able to express the integral in any simpler form.  You could certainly numerically compute a definite integral for any interval within $(0,\pi)$ to get a function.  Each interval of length $\pi$ might have a different constant of integration.  [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20of%20sin(x)%5E(sin(x))) gives the definite integral from $0$ to $\pi$ as about $2.60589$ and gives a messy series expansion for the indefinite integral valid near zero

Comment: but for $\sin(x)<0$ we have a complex value for the integral, right?

Comment: You could.  I assumed you were working in the reals.  To handle complex numbers you have to carefully choose the branch of the complex logarithm you want to work on.  You still won't have a simple expression for the integral.